# Is it possible to define $\lor$ in terms of $\Rightarrow$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is it possible to define $\lor$ in terms of $\Rightarrow$? 
I used a truth table to show that $p \lor q$ and $(p \Rightarrow q) \Rightarrow q$  have the same values for all possible combinations of $(p,q)$. I am yet not sure if it is enough to say that $\lor$ can be "defined" by $\Rightarrow$

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means.

Comment: You've proved it using truth tables. Another way is through equivalences. Use the formula $p\Rightarrow q$ is equivalent (equiv.) to $\lnot p\lor q$.

$(p\Rightarrow q)\Rightarrow q$ is equiv. to $\lnot (\lnot p\lor q)\lor q$ is equiv. to by De Morgan's laws $(\lnot\lnot p\land \lnot q)\lor q$ is equiv. to $(p\land \lnot q)\lor q$ is equiv. to by distributive laws $(p\lor q)\land (\lnot q\lor q)$ is equiv. to $(p\lor q)\land 1$ is equiv. to $p\lor q$.

Comment: In two-valued logic this is true. In fuzzy logic $p\Rightarrow q$ and $\neg p\lor q$ are no longer the same thing. For two fuzzy sets $P$ and $Q$, $P\subset Q$ does not imply $\bar{P}\cup Q=U$, the universe of discourse. The latter condition is stronger.

Comment: @ZhuoranHe In fuzzy logic, you usually define V in terms of  ⇒ as Amelius described.  Yes, in standard fuzzy logic, (p⇒q) and (¬p∨q) are no longer the same thing.